# Display the page of a specified URL, instead of the default or blank page, when the user opens a new tab

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to port a simple Chrome extension to Firefox add-on/extension. The code for the Chrome Extension is:

**manifest.json**

```json
{
  ...
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "javascripts/background.js"
    ]
  },
  "chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "main.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

**main.html**

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: none;">
    <iframe src='http://google.com' width='100%' height='100%' frameborder='0' seamless></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

**javascripts/background.js**

```javascript
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { url: 'http://google.com' });
});
```

In Firefox, I created a Firefox SDK-addon and I ended up with:

**lib/main.js**

```javascript
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
var tabs = require('sdk/tabs');
var self = require('sdk/self');
var pageUrl = self.data.url('main.html')

var button = buttons.ActionButton({
  id: 'mozilla-link',
  label: 'Googler',
  icon: {
    '16': './images/icon16.png',
    '32': './images/icon32.png',
    '64': './images/icon64.png'
  },
  onClick: handleClick
});

function handleClick(state) {
  tabs.open('http://google.com/');
}

tabs.on('activate', function(tab) {
  tab.url = 'http://google.com/'
});
```

but it's not working properly and I don't want the URLto be shown on the URL-bar.

I want to display a given website once the user opens a new tab. I don't mind if the user knows the actual URL, but I think that populate the URL-bar is kinda annoying since the user has to delete the URL (in this case google.com) in order to put a new one.

I want to have the same behaviour as usepanda.com. Their extension overrides the newtab page and shows the Panda website. Obviously, the user is aware of this behaviour when he downloads the extension.

How can I achieve the same functionality? I've thinking on using XUL and overlays, but I'm a bit lost.

Comment: There are a variety of ways you could do this.  However, showing the actual URL in the URL-bar is considered a security issue. Why do you want to make it appear to the user that they are at google.com, or some other site, when they are not?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Xan I want to have the same behaviour as usepanda.com. Their extension overrides the newtab page and shows the Panda website. Obviously, the user is aware of this behaviour when he downloads the extension.

Comment: Oh, nevermind, this question is for making a Firefox addon. I misread it.

Comment: @Makyen I want to display a given website once the user opens a new tab. I don't mind if the user knows the actual URL, but I think that populate the URL-bar is kinda annoying since the user has to delete the URL (in this case google.com) in order to put a new one. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So... are you trying to make it such that a specific URL is opened whenever a user opens a NEW tab (i.e. a tab that is opened as a blank tab by the user, *not* one opened by the user following a link and specifying that the link be opened in a new tab)?

Comment: @Makyen exactly, only when the user opens a new (empty) tab. If the user clicks on a link, the standard behavior should be applied.

Answer (score 2):

After some questioning, we now know that what you want is: Make it such that a specific URL is opened whenever a user opens a NEW tab (i.e. a tab that is opened as a blank tab by the user, not one opened by the user following a link and specifying that the link be opened in a new tab):

There are many extensions that do this already.  I suggest that you check the code for them.  Personally, I use [*Tab Utilities*](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-utilities/), but it has *much* more functionality than you are looking for.

A [very quick search on Mozilla Add-ons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=set%20URL%20for%20new%20tab&appver=32.0.2&platform=WINNT) produced the [*New Tab Homepage*](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-tab-homepage/?src=search) which is very small and appears to do something very close to what you want as an [overlay extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions).  On the other hand, it looks like *Custom New Tab* does **exactly** what you want. However, it is a [Restartless/Bootstraped extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions) which makes it more complicated.  Thus, I will show [*New Tab Homepage*](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-tab-homepage/?src=search) below.

As mentioned, [*New Tab Homepage*](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-tab-homepage/?src=search) is an overlay extension. I did not quickly see an extension listed that does this which was based on the Add-on SDK.  Thus, this is not quite what you appear to have requested.

**The code from [*New Tab Homepage*](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-tab-homepage/?src=search):**

Javascript (*chrome/content/tabhomepage.js*):

```
/* ***** BEGIN LICENSE BLOCK *****
 * Version: MPL 1.1/GPL 2.0/LGPL 2.1
 *
 * The contents of this file are subject to the Mozilla Public License Version
 * 1.1 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 * the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
 * http://www.mozilla.org/MPL/
 *
 * Software distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" basis,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License
 * for the specific language governing rights and limitations under the
 * License.
 *
 * The Original Code is New Tab Homepage.
 *
 * The Initial Developer of the Original Code is
 *   Ben Basson <ben@basson.at>
 * Portions created by the Initial Developer are Copyright (C) 2005
 * the Initial Developer. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Contributor(s):
 *   Ben Basson <ben@basson.at>
 *
 * Alternatively, the contents of this file may be used under the terms of
 * either the GNU General Public License Version 2 or later (the "GPL"), or
 * the GNU Lesser General Public License Version 2.1 or later (the "LGPL"),
 * in which case the provisions of the GPL or the LGPL are applicable instead
 * of those above. If you wish to allow use of your version of this file only
 * under the terms of either the GPL or the LGPL, and not to allow others to
 * use your version of this file under the terms of the MPL, indicate your
 * decision by deleting the provisions above and replace them with the notice
 * and other provisions required by the GPL or the LGPL. If you do not delete
 * the provisions above, a recipient may use your version of this file under
 * the terms of any one of the MPL, the GPL or the LGPL.
 *
 * ***** END LICENSE BLOCK ***** */

var newtabhomepage = {

  init: function ()
  {
    gBrowser.removeEventListener("NewTab", BrowserOpenTab, false);
    window.BrowserOpenTab = newtabhomepage.opentab;

    // explicitly add new listener
    gBrowser.addEventListener("NewTab", newtabhomepage.opentab, false);

    newtabhomepage.prefs = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1']
                           .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefService);
  },

  opentab: function (aEvent)
  {
    // Firefox allows multiple piped homepages, take the first if necessary
    var homepage = gHomeButton.getHomePage().split("|")[0];
    var newtab = gBrowser.addTab(homepage);
    if (newtabhomepage.prefs.getBoolPref("newtabhomepage.selectnewtab"))
    {
      gBrowser.selectedTab = newtab;
      if (gURLBar)
        setTimeout(function() { 
          // if page is about:blank select() works just like focus, two birds one stone
          gURLBar.select();
        }, 0);
    }
    if (aEvent)
      aEvent.stopPropagation();

    return newtab;
  }

}

window.addEventListener("load",newtabhomepage.init,false);
```

To get what you want you can edit the JavaScript to make the assignment of the URL be to something static.

XUL overlay  (*chrome/content/tabhomepage.xul*):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
  ***** BEGIN LICENSE BLOCK *****
  Version: MPL 1.1/GPL 2.0/LGPL 2.1

  The contents of this file are subject to the Mozilla Public License Version
  1.1 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
  http://www.mozilla.org/MPL/

  Software distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" basis,
  WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License
  for the specific language governing rights and limitations under the
  License.

  The Original Code is New Tab Homepage.

  The Initial Developer of the Original Code is
    Ben Basson <ben@basson.at>
  Portions created by the Initial Developer are Copyright (C) 2005
  the Initial Developer. All Rights Reserved.

  Contributor(s):
    Ben Basson <ben@basson.at>

  Alternatively, the contents of this file may be used under the terms of
  either the GNU General Public License Version 2 or later (the "GPL"), or
  the GNU Lesser General Public License Version 2.1 or later (the "LGPL"),
  in which case the provisions of the GPL or the LGPL are applicable instead
  of those above. If you wish to allow use of your version of this file only
  under the terms of either the GPL or the LGPL, and not to allow others to
  use your version of this file under the terms of the MPL, indicate your
  decision by deleting the provisions above and replace them with the notice
  and other provisions required by the GPL or the LGPL. If you do not delete
  the provisions above, a recipient may use your version of this file under
  the terms of any one of the MPL, the GPL or the LGPL.

 ***** END LICENSE BLOCK ***** -->

<overlay id="tabhomepageOverlay"
  xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
  xmlns:nc="http://home.netscape.com/NC-rdf#">

  <script type="application/x-javascript"
    src="chrome://tabhomepage/content/tabhomepage.js"/>

</overlay>
```

chrome.manifest:

```
overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul    chrome://tabhomepage/content/tabhomepage.xul
content tabhomepage chrome/content/
```

install.rdf:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">

  <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">

    <em:id>{66E978CD-981F-47DF-AC42-E3CF417C1467}</em:id>
    <em:version>0.4.3</em:version>
    <em:name>New Tab Homepage</em:name>
    <em:description>Loads your homepage when you open a new tab.</em:description>
    <em:creator>Ben Basson</em:creator>
    <em:homepageURL>http://www.cusser.net</em:homepageURL>

    <em:targetApplication>
      <Description>
        <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
        <em:minVersion>3.0b2</em:minVersion>
        <em:maxVersion>4.0.*</em:maxVersion>
      </Description>
    </em:targetApplication>

  </Description>

</RDF>
```

Preferences JavaScript (*defaults/preferences/tabhomepage.js*):

```
/* Focus newly created tabs */
pref("newtabhomepage.selectnewtab", true);
```

That is the entirety of the [*New Tab Homepage*](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-tab-homepage/?src=search) extension.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jetpack you can reset the global like this:

```
var { get, set } = require("sdk/preferences/service");
var { when: unload } = require("sdk/system/unload");
var oldValue = get("browser.newtab.url");
set("browser.newtab.url", "http://somedomain.com" );
unload(function() {
  set("browser.newtab.url", oldValue);
});
```

[Firefox SDK preferences/service](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/preferences_service)

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
var {Cu} = require('chrome');
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
var newuri = Services.io.newURI('http://www.bing.com/', null, null);
Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser').gBrowser.selectedTab.linkedBrowser.webNavigation.setCurrentURI(newuri);
```

To test it out open up scratchpad, go to menu bar, set it Environment to Browser, then run it, it will change your current tab to say bing.com